# APK-файл на устанавливается на Android API 15

Tags: android, android-sdk, proguard, multidex

В проекте установок на android 4.0.4 очень мало и недавно пришел человек с жалобой что на его телефон с такой версией приложение не ставится. Я проверяю на эмуляторе и понимаю, что приложение для этой версии, якобы, слишком велико (MultiDex использую), судя по гуглению этой ошибки в Интернете.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Размер apk около 12мб. Я включаю ProGuard, вношу все правила по используемым библиотекам в proguard-rules.pro, **отключаю обфускацию**, **отключаю оптимизацию**, проект собирается, ставится на устройство, оно его устанавливает, но в рантейме происходят ошибки, связанные с no such method и т.п.

Вопрос: может можно как-то по-другому обойти, не мучаясь с ProGuard?

И почему, вдруг, эта проблема только на 15 версии? На 16 всё хорошо..

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена более точной и подробной настройкой proguard-rules.pro файла.